# Dependency is not satisfiable: python3 (>= 3.9~)

Tags: software-installation

What exactly does the following error mean, and how do I resolve it? It came up when I tried to install a package Thank you!

`Dependency is not satisfiable: python3 (>= 3.9~)`

Comment: What version Ubuntu are you running?  Ubuntu 20.04 uses python 3.8, so your package requires a later package, 3.9 or later.  What package is this?

Comment: This kind of error usually occurs when you are trying to do something very unwise, like installing packages that are incompatible with your release of Ubuntu. Please edit your question to include complete input and output showing what you are trying to install, from which source, onto which release of Ubuntu, and the resulting failure.

Comment: The error message is written in plain language. However, you must understand how Debian package dependencies and Debian-based release snapshots work in order for that plain language to make sense. Generally, you "resolve" the error by learning those concepts. Then you understand *why* asking for a wrong-version package is unwise.

Answer (score 1):

The package you are trying to install requires Python 3.9 or above.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3 says that Ubuntu 21.04 has python version 3.9, whereas Ubuntu 20.04 has Python 3.8 by default. You would need Ubuntu 21.04 to use the package you were trying to install.

You can also install Python 3.9 in supported LTS versions of Ubuntu with the [Deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), but the name of that python package will be `python3.9`, and the package you were trying to install will probably still refuse to install (because it requires `python3` to have a version `>= 3.9`). In that case, you would have to download the source package, and rebuild it to work with `python3.9` (that is a lot of work).

If you let us know about the package you were trying to install, we can try to help you install it.

You should not try to install .deb files built for one version of Ubuntu in another version (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software) question). That may break dependency cycles, and you would have to reinstall to fix it.